# Docker containers in read-only mode

Tags: docker

still pretty new to docker and i could use some help. I am trying to setup some docker containers precisely the redash appplication. Here is my working code:

```
sudo docker network create redash_default
sudo docker container run --name redis --network redash_default -d redis:4.0-alpine
sudo docker container run --name postgres --network redash_default --env-file /opt/redash/env -v /opt/redash/postgres-data -d postgres:9.5.21-alpine
sudo docker container run --rm -p 5000:5000 -e REDASH_WEB_WORKERS=4 --name server --network redash_default --env-file env redash/redash:7.0.0.b18042 create_db
sudo docker container run -d --restart always -p 5000:5000 -e REDASH_WEB_WORKERS=4 --name server --network redash_default --env-file env redash/redash:7.0.0.b18042

sudo docker container run -d --restart always -e QUEUES=celery -e WORKERS_COUNT=1 --name scheduler --network redash_default --env-file env redash/redash:7.0.0.b18042

sudo docker container run -d --restart always -e QUEUES=scheduled_queries,schemas -e WORKERS_COUNT=1 --name scheduled_worker --network redash_default --env-file env redash/redash:7.0.0.b18042

sudo docker container run -d --restart always -e QUEUES=queries -e WORKERS_COUNT=2 --name adhoc_worker --network redash_default --env-file env redash/redash:7.0.0.b18042

sudo docker container run -d --restart always -p 80:80 --link server:redash --name nginx --network redash_default redash/nginx:latest
```

however i am only allowed to run the containers in read-only mode which is breaking the application. Only redis seemed to like the read-only mode so i thought about mounting an external persistent disk on the instance /dockervol/ where the apps can be given RW access but i cant seem to get that work either. here is something i have tried for example with nginx

```
docker container run -p 80:80 --mount type=bind,source=/dockervol/nginx,target=/etc/nginx – read-only --link server:redash --name nginx --network redash_default redash/nginx:latest
```

i get an error

*nginx: [emerg] open() “/etc/nginx/nginx.conf” failed (2: No such file or directory)*

My question is how do i get all the containers to work in read-only mode with a persistent volume without breaking the application.

Comment: Hi, does `source=/dockervol/nginx` contains also your nginx.conf? And why do you ned storage in your nginx container?

Comment: @CLNRMN, thanks for pointing this out, i do actually have the nginx.conf but it was in the wrong directory. for the storage portion, our servers get re imaged every month. so i thought it would be a good idea to have a storage for it.

Comment: open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (30: Read-only file system) is the error i get when i put nginx.conf in the right directory caused by the read-only flag i believe.

Comment: I would recommend to only mount the files/directories which you need in the container as RedOnly (like the nginx.conf if you have modified it). Nginx need some writable files like the nginx.pid.

e.q. `docker run -p 80:80 -v /tmp/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro redash/nginx`